# Lync 2010 - Operation was unsuccessful

Tags: lync

I'm trying to get Lync 2010 work in my lab environment. 
I've got a domain controller, a single lync server, a client and a SIP gateway. I've gotten to the part where I have a successfull login from the client to the lync server. I set up a few routes for testing, and made sure the output looks like I want it to when it's passed through Lync.

However, I have a problem when I try to make the call from the client!

The client reports: Operation was unsuccessful. The calling service did not respont. Wait and then try again.

Is this a typical error generated from a misconfiguration in the Lync server, or could this be the a problem with the SIP gateway?

What logs would I dig through, and where do I find them?

Any pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: You might try starting with the applications logs in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Great tip! Can't beleive I didn't check the applogs on the server.. It says the PBX gateway isn't replying, so that kinda narrows it down! I know who to hit in the head now ;) Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Some applications "plug in" correctly while others write their own logs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by checking applogs.
Seems like a misconfigured PBX, which didn't want to reply on the correct port.